# No true result return in insert query

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the class I have created which I am using for the queries:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX | MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

class DBConnect {
    private $dbcon;
    private $paramquery;
    private $result;

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->dbcon = mysqli_init();
            mysqli_real_connect($this->dbcon, '127.0.0.1', '', '', '', 3306, '', MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
            $this->paramquery = $this->dbcon->stmt_init();
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            exit('Database Connection Failed');
        }
    }
    public function dbquery($querysql, $querydata) {
        try {
            mysqli_ping($this->dbcon);
            $this->paramquery->prepare($querysql);

            array_walk($querydata, function(&$escval){$escval = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->dbcon, $escval);});   //Problem
            call_user_func_array(array($this->paramquery, 'bind_param'), $querydata);   //Problem

            $this->paramquery->execute();
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            exit('Database Query Failed');
        }

        $this->result = $this->paramquery->get_result();  // problem

        if ($this->result) {
            $drs = $this->result->fetch_array();
            $this->result->free_result();
            return $drs;
        }
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        if (($this->dbcon !== null) && ($this->paramquery !== null) && ($this->result !== null)) {
            $this->paramquery->close();
            $this->dbcon->close();
        }
        unset($this->result);
        unset($this->paramquery);
        unset($this->dbcon);
    }
}
?>
```

The index.php file code is this:

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');

$DBX = new DBConnect();

$DBX->dbquery('INSERT INTO `xathx_key` (`license`, `client`, `server`, `uniquex`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', array('ssss', '1', '3', '5', '7'));

var_dump($DBX);
unset($DBX)
?>
```

I am trying to do an INSERT query in this instance. And I want to get a success result or flag when the query is executed successfully. But in the var_dump of the object I get some irrelevant data and if I use echo I get an error that the object cannot be converted to a string. I just want to get a 0 for query execution failure, corruption or problem and a 1 for completion, success, ok status. When am I going wrong in the code?

EDIT: Can you guys just tell me what are the things that are wrong with this simple script? The main goal of this script is to connect to mysql server and execute all possible queries as fast as possible, as securely as possible.

Full Project Source: https://github.com/FSMySQL/PHP-FSMySQL

Comment: Why do you need this number? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: need the status for verifying the query succession or failure.

Comment: **why** do you need to verify? What are you going to do in case of failure?

Comment: That kinda weird question. In case of a failure I am going to call another function which handles the user in an informative manner, as we always do in programming.

Comment: To call such a function, you don't need this number. Read how to do [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) properly. Only you will need an exception handler function in addition to the error handler function

Comment: You do not need `mysqli_real_escape_string` id you use prepared statements and you bind the data.

Comment: did you see in the array the values are 5 and not 4?

Answer (score 5):

> The main goal of this script is to connect to mysql server and execute all possible queries as fast as possible, as securely as possible.

The goal is a good one but the implementation could benefit from many improvements.

Disclaimer: there will be a lot of links to my own site because I am helping people with PHP for 20+ years and got an obsession with writing articles about most common issues.

#### The concept of error reporting

First of all, you need to change *the concept of error reporting*. Your `exit()` approach would be a *nightmare* for a programmer, as error messages are *a vital source of information when something goes wrong*. A programmer should go at any lengths trying to get the error message in the full detail. In my article, [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting), I do explain how to make error reporting both programmer- and user-friendly. In short, you shouldn't catch errors on the spot, but have a single dedicated place to report errors and exceptions, and then it could be easily configured depends on the current server's role.

Although, as suggested in the other answer, you could use a global try-catch block in your index.php file to act as such a global error handler, I would prefer a dedicated error handler script, as explained in the article above. It will make your code better organized and make index.php less bloated.

Besides, your idea of having "a true result return in insert query" contradicts with your intention to use exceptions. When one is using exceptions, there is no point to verify the immediate function's result. In case of error it will just bubble up to the error handler or a catch block, so, it will never reach the condition. A quick example:

```
function test() {
    throw new Exception("Test");
    return false;
}
$result = test();
if ($result === false) {
    echo "false";
}
```

The code execution in this example **will never reach the condition**, therefore making your functions return false on error useless. Which, in turn, makes returning true on success superfluous. Just return a meaningful result but don't use it as flag: simply write your code without any conditions, as though everything is fine. Remember that you have your error handling code elsewhere that will be magically invoked in case of error.

#### Connection

As explained in my other article, [How to connect properly using mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect), there is a slight chance to reveal connection credentials in case of a connection error. To avoid even a possibility but keep the programmer informed we have to throw a *brand new exception*, however keeping the error information - so the stack trace will begin from the throw line, and thus contain no sensitive information.

Also, the connection code lacks an essential part - *setting the correct charset*. Although in MySQL 8 the correct charset is set by default, it's better to make it explicit.

Also, making a mysqli statement a class variable is a grave mistake that will lead to [race condition errors](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#statefulness). The only state that your class should keep is that related to the connection but not a single class variable should be used for a statement.

So let's rewrite your constructor based on the code from the article above:

```
public function __construct()
{
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX | MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    try {
        $this->dbcon = mysqli_init();
        $this->dbcon->real_connect('127.0.0.1', '', '', '', 3306, '', MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
        $this->dbcon->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    } catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

#### The dbquery function

The function is, frankly, weird. It's a strange mix between prepared statements and escaping. Let's rewrite it based on my [mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) that actually utilizes mysqli prepared statements

```
public function dbquery($sql, $data = [], $types = "")
{
        $this->dbcon->ping(); // not sure if it's necessary 
        $stmt = $this->dbcon->prepare($sql);
        if ($data) {
            $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($data));
            $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$data);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result();
}
```

*Now* this function fulfills your desire for secure SQL queries

So finally we can rewrite your index.php

```
<?php

require_once('connection.php');
$DBX = new DBConnect();

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `xathx_key` (`license`, `client`, `server`, `uniquex`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$DBX->dbquery($sql, ['1', '3', '5', '7']);
```

Just as you learned above, there is no need for a "flag when the query is executed successfully". Just act as though there is always a success. In case of error it will appear without any conditions (an on a live site will be handled properly if you include an error handler script in your index).

Answer (score 0):

In your `DBConnect` Class, you have try catch blocks. But your catch blocks are simply terminating the request using `exit` statement. Your Class should not be doing that.

Imagine you deploy this on production and for some reason the DB Connection Fails. In that case User will simply see a white screen with Message "Database Connection Failed" which would not look professional at all.

Instead your class should pass this information back to the `index.php` which called the method of this Class and let `index.php` handle the Error Message or Exception.

So I would make following changes to your code:

1. `DBConnect` Class should throw an Exception rather than terminating the execution of the program completely. Below is how the `__contruct()` should look.

```
    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->dbcon = mysqli_init();
            mysqli_real_connect($this->dbcon, '127.0.0.1', '', '', '', 3306, '', MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS);
            $this->paramquery = $this->dbcon->stmt_init();
        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            //exit('Database Connection Failed'); Commented this out.
            //Throw the Exception Here. This will then be passed to the calling code.
            throw $e;
        }
    }
```

You will need to change the other methods accordingly.

2. In your `index.php` File, you should be looking to catch the above exception. So you should move your code in a Try Catch Block to catch that exception.

```
require_once('connection.php');

try {
    $DBX = new DBConnect();
    $DBX->dbquery('INSERT INTO `xathx_key` (`license`, `client`, `server`, `uniquex`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', array('ssss', '1', '3', '5', '7'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message =  'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    //Display this Message to User in an appropriate way.
    //Write to Error Log
}

//var_dump($DBX);
//unset($DBX)
```

So this will catch the Exception in case the DB Connection Fails as well as when the Insert Query Fails. You can write the exception to the logs so that you can check them later and you can display any appropriate error message to user based on the exception caused.

You could read more on Exceptions in [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: there is no point in converting a specific mysqli_sql_exception into a generic Exception, it spoils the whole idea of different exception classes

Comment: @YourCommonSense You are right, there is no point throwing a new exception. I have updated answer.

Comment: now I don't see a point in catching and then throwing *exactly the same* exception.

Comment: That is the example they have given at https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php#110971 Perhaps there is a better way but I am not aware.

Comment: Oh, that's just a cargo cult code in that comment :) I'll show the correct way in my answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense `there is no point in converting a specific mysqli_sql_exception into a generic Exception, it spoils the whole idea of different exception classes` Yet you did the same (almost) in your answer.

Comment: @ascsoftw By `they` you are referring to user contributed notes. That is not an official example from PHP devs/doc-maintainers. The user contributed notes on php.net are usualy bullsense. Never ever take them as holy.

Comment: @slepic good question. I do not `convert a specific mysqli_sql_exception into a generic Exception`. I keep **the same** exception which is important. A "mysqli_sql_exception" already means in PHP "A problem with a database", which makes `throw new Exception('Database Connection Failed.' . $e->getMessage());` unnecessarily verbose and less flexible (you can catch an exception by the name but cannot by the message). The idea here is [to keep the credentials hidden](https://3v4l.org/3Ygq8) (at the cost of the lost backtrace tho).

Comment: @YourCommonSense yeah thats why I wrote the "almost". But If it was a child of mysqli_sql_exception you still convert it to more generic mysqli_sql_exception (which honestly idk if it has any children). And yes you are not passing the exception as the previous one. My point was that in such case you probably shouldnt catch the exception at all and just have the original one bubble up the stream. The idea with hiding credentials is wrong IMO, since any sane developer will not have display any piece of the exception in production environement. So this should be secured on a different level...

Comment: @slepic initially I kept to exactly the same notion and recommended not to catch. And as you can see from my answer, I strictly recommend this rule... as a rule. However, after a lot of discussion I decided that it's better to be safe than sorry and a connection is a very special case. Even if it won't show on the screen, but flashing your credentials in the error log is no good either.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with

```
$this->result = $this->paramquery->get_result();
```

because [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) `returns a resultset for successful SELECT queries, or FALSE for other DML queries or on failure.`

`Other DML-queries` are INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. And that's exactly what you have in the example.

To resolve your problem you can modify the class by adding some extra-checks to `$mysqli->errno`:

```
$this->result = $this->paramquery->get_result();
if ($this->result) {
    ...
}

if ($this->paramquery->errno !== 0) { // we have some real error
    exit('Database Query Failed');
}

// we have DML-query (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
// and we can return number of affected rows (if it's necessary)
return $this->paramquery->affected_rows;
```

---

P.S. I agree with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57782717/3456163) and I think that your class should be used for educational purposes only because it has multiple serious flaws.